# REP 120: not clear about odom and base_footprint

Tags: navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have question, on odom and base_footprint, especially when the robot is falling down or 4-legged walking in  [REP 120](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0120.html).
I assume that humanoid robot did not know about the current waist position, but can estimate orientation from IMU sensors.

1. does odom correspond to the sensor based orientation and world reference based position of the waist?
2. does base_footprint respect the sensor based orientation and model based calculation of the height of the waist?

if it is ok, the question is

1. how do you estimate the position of the odom, from the walking controllers? does that include any sensor data?
2. does base_footprint does not reflect any sensor data? what's happens if the robot falling down or 4-legged walking mode?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94941/rep-120:-not-clear-about-odom-and-base_footprint/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2013-10-27

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Okasa-san,

as for mobile robots, every frames on top of `base_link` are actively relying on the localization / SLAM node and therefore the result you will obtain will depend in these particular cases will depend on how it behaves.

In my case, I use `robot_pose_ekf` (on HRP2) so that I both combine the integration of the command *and* the IMU data. The `odom` is published by this node like on PR2.

For `base_footprint`, I use the point defined as the center of the robot soles center. If you walk on non-flat floor, of course you have to project this point at the right height depending on your perception. This is not an issue on flat-floor although.
This definition works fine for any number of legs.

If the robot is falling then of course the "footprint" is not really a footprint anymore but it is still defined (mathematically speaking). As for the `odom` frame, by changing the covariance matrices appropriately you can only integrate the IMU data when you fall to get an estimate of your position.

P.S. FYI the `robot_pose_ekf` node input is an odometry message sent by the robot controller (hrpsys in my case).

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2013-10-28**:
Thanks, so what is the tf structure ?
map -> odom -> robot_pose_ekl -> base_link -> base_footprint?

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2013-10-28**:
Another question is that , the orientation of the the robot is not precisely equal to (0 0 1), as there are elastic material on the sole and ankle, also mechanical backlash, in that case, does 'base_footprint' orientation is (0 0 1)? or it should correspond to real orientation of the robot?

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-10-28**:
The frame hiearchy is here:
http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0120.html#id17 and http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html#relationship-between-frames
I.e.
map -> odom -> base_link -> base_footprint

You would observe a different behavior on PR2 but PR2 does not follow REP 105 unfornately.

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-10-28**:
The `base_footprint` rotational part is undefined in the current state of the REP. IMHO this is not the best frame to express contacts so I would keep the rotational part to identity if I were you. That does not prevent you to add additional tf frames to express contact points position.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. odom is an inertial frame defined in [REP 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) It can be initialized anywhere in any orientation, but for ease of use usually it's x forward y left z up under the robot's initial position.
2. Nominally the base_footprint is the projection of the robot's shape into a 2D form on the ground.  Usually this is approximated as a set of primitives (sometimes one) in the ground plane directly under the base_link in the XY plane.
3. You can/should use any/all sensors to compute the best odometric updates for your robot.  They will provide the transform from odom -> base_link.
4. When you consider a robot which is tall but might change to a recumbent position the footprint extend to make sure to remain a bounding box if using the footprint for navigation.  Note the coordinate frame will not really update as it will still be the projection of the base_link (recommended attached to the waist) into the XY plane.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3